# Assets 2.0.2 Fatal error

Tags: add-on, assets

I just updated Assets 2.0.2 from 1.x and on one of the pages of our site, we're receiving the following fatal error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'unknown_source' in ...expressionengine/third_party/assets/libraries/assets_lib.php:1188

I'm not sure, but I think it has something to do with upload preferences.  I should note that in the code at line 1188, the $settings variable being inspected is not empty, though when tested the Exception is still being thrown.

Has anyone experienced this, and if so, is there a fix?  Or is there some configuration setting that I'm missing?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Please direct bug reports directly to developers - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This error will be fixed in the upcoming Assets 2.0.3 release.